# Find my question about Windows Explorer?

Tags: support

I asked a question about save dialogs: I was trying to find a method by which to add more than Favorites, Libraries, Homegroup, My Computer, etc., to Windows Explorer on the left-hand pain.  I ended up accepting an answer that suggested a program.  The program allowed total customization of that left-side pain, even allowing me to remove useless items like Homegroup and Network.

Can someone help me find that question, so I don't end up duplicating it?  I'm afraid I may have asked it elsewhere, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Second one in [this list](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A69724+is%3Aquestion+dialog) maybe?

[Add-remove folders of left-side of “Save As”, Notepad++; other applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/741797/add-remove-folders-of-left-side-of-save-as-notepad-other-applications)

You can see your previous questions [on your profile](https://superuser.com/users/69724/wolfpack08?tab=questions&sort=newest)